Customizing {modelsummary} output to match {sjPlot::tab_model} for glmer
I try to customize the output of modelsummary::modelsummary() to match the output of sjPlot::tab_model()- simply, to achieve similar looking tables when the output is PDF compared to HTML.
sjPlot::tab_model()

modelsummary::modelsummary()

Statistically the output is the same, and I am able to calculate the individual numbers (see code below) but I fail to define a customized tidy.lmerMod and/or glance.lmerMod - and I am wondering if the argument add_rows is better suited for my usecase?
Below is code which I tried in a quarto document:
---
format: html
echo: true
---

## Test

```{r}

library(lme4)
library(modelsummary)

# fit example model (from help page)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1| Subject), sleepstudy)

#sjPlot-output
sjPlot::tab_model(fm1)

# modelsummary-output
modelsummary(fm1, gof_map = c("nobs", "r2.conditional", "r2.marginal"))
```


### Ideas how to approach

I can calculate all the numbers, see examples below

```{r}
# getting Sigma^2 = 
# SD (Observations)^2 or insight::get_variance_residual(fm1)

# getting Tau subject =
# SD (intercept subject)^2 or insight::get_variance_random(fm1)

# getting ICC1=
# get_gof$icc or
# SD (intercept subject)^2 / (SD (intercept subject)^2 + SD (Observations)^2)

```

The code below did not help, neither did loading {broom.mixed} explicitly - there was no error, but the output did not change at all. And given the lack of error message, I am lost.
```{r}
# tidy_custom.lmerMod <- function(x, ...) {
#   tibble::tibble(
#     "Var Subject" = insight::get_variance_random(x)[[1]],
#     "Total" = insight::get_variance_residual(x)[[1]],
#   )
# }
```

Thankful for any ideas on how to best approach this!

See the documentation for the shape argument. Not exactly the same but will likely get you closer. https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary.html#shape
